# I am getting SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?

Tags: python

```
faces = face_classifier.detectMultiScale(image, 1.3, 5)
if faces is ():
print('No Face found')
```

> <>:1: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
>   <>:1: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
>   :1: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
>     if faces is ():

Comment: `if faces == ()` or `if not faces`

Comment: Use `==` for value comparisons and `is` for object identity comparisons. Your lines means: Is `faces` the exact same object as `()`.

Comment: Okay, did you *read* the warning? Did you see the part where it suggests a different way to write the code? Do you have an actual *question*?